How can I define a function with structures in C?
I'm working on a C program with the following files:
functiontest.h
double funcCmp(double(*func1)(double), double(*func2)(double), 
               double xM, double xI, int xN, enum NormType ntype) {
 …
  }
  return err; 
}

double updateErr(double errPrev, double val1, double val2, enum NormType ntype) {
  …
  return errCurr; 
}

utile.h
long computeElapsedTime(struct timeval start, struct timeval end)
{
}

and two more files from my textbook (trig.h and trig.c) containing the declaration and definition of the functions cos, sin, and tangent.
When I first compiled, I obtained the following error:
util.h:22:6: error: redefinition computeElapsedTime function

which I fixed by adding the following macro at the beginning of the files utile.h, testfunction.h, and fasttrigo.h.
#ifndef SO_UTILE_H_
#define SO_UTILE_H_
..
#endif

However, now I have another error:
conflicting types for ‘updateErr’

which I believe is thrown because the declaration and definition of the functions happen in the same files instead of separate files. However, I’m having a hard time declaring them because I don’t know how to define functions with struct parameters.

First you need to learn the difference between declarations and definitions: A declarations tells the compiler that a thing exists somewhere; And a definition is the implementation of the thing. For functions, place only declarations in the header files, and the definitions in one single source file.

Also, you must declare functions before you want to call them.

You have to put only declarations in the header (.h) file, something like this:
double updateErr(double errPrev, double val1, double val2, enum NormType ntype);
The actual code (function definitions) you posted then goes into a .c file

I've VTC as this is a duplicate.  It's not obvious that its a duplicate until you understand the answer, but the explaination of why you are getting the error you are getting is that, in fact, you have a in implicit declaration of updateErr on the line err = updateErr(err, y_1, y_2, ntype);.  As mentioned in the linked answer, C is a very old language, and some of the choices made were not the ones we find natural today.

@Gigi, aside: return ((end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec))/1000.0; has overflow and unneeded conversion issues.  A pedantic alternative: return (long) (((0LL + end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000 + (0L + end.tv_usec - start.tv_sec))/1000);.

@ilikeMUDs Nice to see that there are still people around that like MUDs... ;-)
